# Creating a menu layout in XML android studio

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea, layout

I am getting an unknown class error while creating a menu layout.XMl in android studio. Might someone please help me to solve this issues?
The compiler does not recognize the attribute "item".

```
<item android:id=”@+id/about”

android:title=”About” />
<item android:id=”@+id/help”
android:title=”Help” />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a menu before them and put in this directory **res/menu/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
        android:title="about" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_ help"
        android:title="help"/>
</menu>
```